# Why DeviceInformation.Name does not display correct name

Tags: c#, windows, uwp, windows-runtime

I am developing custom HID device. I can see the name in device manager (MyCustomDevice). However when I find the device using `DeviceWatcher`, the `DeviceInformation.Name` property has value `Unknown USB Device (Port Reset Failed)`. Other applications using WIN32 apis can get correct name of device without problem.

My code:

```
// Selector for enabled HID devices
string selector = "System.Devices.InterfaceClassGuid:=\"{4D1E55B2-F16F-11CF-88CB-001111000030}\" AND System.Devices.InterfaceEnabled:=System.StructuredQueryType.Boolean#True";
_watcher = DeviceInformation.CreateWatcher(selector, properties);
_watcher.Added += (s, deviceInformation) => {
    Console.WriteLine(deviceInformation.Name); // prints "Unknown USB Device (Port Reset Failed)"
};
```

Device functions correctly, I can communicate with it - the only problem is this `Name`. Is there possibility to fix it other than going back to WIN32?

To clarify things:
The device uses standard `hidusb.sys` driver, and there are no yellow exclamation marks in device manager.

Comment: There is a windows standard for adding Device Name to a hardware object which limits the number of characters allowed.  The device driver reads the name from the hardware object and then puts into a window format.  The driver when installing the hardware puts the name into DeviceInformation when registering the device when the machine is started.  Check the driver in Device Manager to see when driver is being used.  One possibility is you are using the standard Microsoft USB driver instead of the vendors driver.

Comment: Could you check if the device has yellow warning where in the `Device Manager`?

Comment: @jdweng I am using standard driver and this is expected. The problem is that win32 reports `MyCustomDevice` as device name, and WinRt apis report `Unknown USB Device (Port Reset Failed)` as device name.

Comment: @NicoZhu-MSFT there is no warning, device works without problem. Also I don't see any errors in event log (but I'm not sure what to look for).

Comment: What's custom hid device? could you share more detail? we can't reproduce your problem

Comment: And have you enabled `humaninterfacedevice` capability?

Comment: the are different version of USB standard( https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/USB).  WinRT is  Microsoft product and be careful how Microsoft implements forward/backward compatibility.  I often do not like the way Microsoft makes there software meets forward/backward compatibility.   I'm guessing the WinRT is using an older version of USB standard and not reading the ID according to latest USB specification.  Or the standard Microsoft driver isn't reading the name properly.  I always use the Vendor Driver where possible because the standard Microsoft driver most of the time do not work properly.